# k-fold cross validation in keras for regression using sklearn

Tags: neural-network, keras, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I am using a wrapper to use sklearn k-fold cross-validation with keras for a regression problem with ANN. but the accuracies i get look very weird. It has worked fine for a classification problem. I am attaching the code too. Is there anything I'm doing wrong

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_regressor():
    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 15))
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
    regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mae'])
    return regressor
regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn = build_regressor, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = 1)
mean = accuracies.mean()
variance = accuracies.std()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean they "look very weird"? Care to share them?

Comment: -15.8012,
-13.6942,
-14.537,
-22.315,
-13.333,
-15.8931,
-16.9658,
-13.4334,
-21.4675,
-39.7934,  these are the 10 values obtained for accuracies

Comment: "Accuracies" is the wrong term here (you are in a regression setting); so these are 10 values of negative MSE (or MAE). What is weird about them?

Comment: I was expecting that "Accuracies" would contain r2_scores,since it is a regression problem. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Well, the API is rather poorly documented, but I would be highly surprised if the Keras people use R^2 at all, which is practically never used in *predictive* contexts; R^2 seems like a fossil from the old statistics era - see the last part of my SO answer [scikit-learn & statsmodels - which R-squared is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct/54618898#54618898) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer through sklearn documentation. The default scoring parameter for cross_val_score is None.So the accuracies that I got are not r2_scores. Since I was expecting them to be r^2 values, I have to mention it as a parameter.

```
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X = X_train, y = y_train,scoring='r2',cv = 10, n_jobs = 1)
```

Adding scoring parameter I was able to get the r2_scores